# React Context - Set state then reference it straight after?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am working with a list of items and I want to set a selected item id, then fetch the selected item using the id.

I am updating the state of a context using reducers which works, but when referencing the property of the state, it doesn't see the updated value.

***Component.js***

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedId(5);
    getSelectedItem();
  }, []);
```

***Context.js***

```
  const initialState = {
    selectedId: 0,
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(ItemReducer, initialState);

  const setSelectedId = id => dispatch({ type: SET_SELECTED_ID, payload: id });

  // HERE IT THINKS 'state.selectedId' IS 0
  const getSelectedItem = async () => {
     const selectedItem = await fetch(url + state.selectedId);
  };
```

[image: Chrome dev tools]

The Chrome dev tools show the selected id property is updated to 5, but the getSelectedItem function sees 'selectedId' as 0 not 5.

This could be a simple issue and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: looks like [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). As mentioned below you cannot access updated id value in the same render run. But what to change depends on what it's your goal. Say why you cannot run `fetch()` in `setSelectedId`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move `getSelectedItem();` into its own useEffect that's dependent on the selectedItemId, that way it will only perform getSelectedItem once the value of selectedId is set.

```
useEffect(() => { 
   if(selectedId) getSelectedItem();
}, [selectedId]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to resolve the promise that would be returned. Something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setSelected(5).then(getSelectedItem());

  }, []);
```

Comment: The setSelected function doesn't return a promise because it is not async, are you implying that I make it async? I was under the assumption that dispatching an action is instant.